# Environment variable available on server, but not on client, even though it's prefixed

Tags: typescript, environment-variables, next.js

I have a `.env.local` file that has three variables set:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_MAGIC_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_test_<get-your-own>
MAGIC_SECRET_KEY=sk_test_<get-your-own>
TOKEN_SECRET=some-secret
```

I print them out in `pages/login.ts`:

```
import UserAuthenticationPage from 'client/features/user-authentication/user-authentication-container';
import redirectIfLoggedIn from 'client/hocs/redirect-if-logged-in';
import { NextPage } from 'next';

(UserAuthenticationPage as NextPage).getInitialProps = async () => {
  console.log('env in login.ts getInitialProps', process.env);
  return {
    namespacesRequired: ['common', 'user-authentication'],
  };
};
console.log('env in login.ts client side', process.env);

export default redirectIfLoggedIn('/')(UserAuthenticationPage);
```

which results in:

```
env in login.ts getInitialProps {
  __NEXT_PROCESSED_ENV: 'true',
  NEXT_PUBLIC_MAGIC_PUBLISHABLE_KEY: 'pk_test_BD092E437FE31429',
  MAGIC_SECRET_KEY: 'sk_test_C02E14264C276A40',
  TOKEN_SECRET: 'my-secret-token-thingy'
}
```

on the server and

```
env in login.ts client side {}
```

on the client. I can also see `Loaded env from /Users/dev/my-nextjs-project/.env.local` printed out when running `next dev`.

Who are the public environment variables not being exposed to the browser?

Comment: I'd imagine they're set for the client at *build* time, not *run* time (this can be a problem, especially with multiple environments, for reasons I expand on in https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html). What does your deployment process look like?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you, that solved it. I had to use [publicRuntimeConfig](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by JonRSharpe, I was able to solve this by using: publicRuntimeConfig.

```
import getConfig from 'next/config';

/**
 * @param key The key of the environment variable you want to get.
 * @throws Throws if the environment variable is absent.
 * @returns The value of the environment variable.
 */
function getEnvironmentVariable(key: string, checkRuntime = false) {
  const variable = process.env[key];

  if (variable) {
    return variable;
  }

  if (checkRuntime) {
    const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();
    const runtimeVariable = publicRuntimeConfig[key];

    if (runtimeVariable) {
      return runtimeVariable;
    }
  }

  throw new Error(`Missing environment variable for key: ${key}.`);
}

export default getEnvironmentVariable;
```